# akka.net can it support millions of stateful actors?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka.net, stateful, akka-persistence

I have a hierarchy like /user/{supervisors}/{children}.  There can be 10s of thousands {supervisors} and equally as many {children} per supervisor.  Both have a complex state and a lot of different messages that each need to be able to handle.

I was considering making {supervisors} and {children} be stateful.  This ends up causing millions of stateful actors.

Can akka handle this?  I would be using clustering and persistence(required of course) to try to spread the load of millions of actors across serveral machines (I assume that clustering with round robin will spread all my actors out equally).

I am new to thinking about stateful development and want to make sure that I am not going to attempt something that is not possible.

Comment: In theory, yes. However, It would depend on many things, such as how much state you have / state size, how many machines you will be clustering, how much ram they have etc... The only way you're going to find out is to measure it.

Comment: Thanks @tomliversidge.  I was planning to make sure everything could live inside memory size.  I am mostly worried that it is a wrong approach.  I guess a better question would have been "Assuming millions of actors will fit in memory is it an acceptable pattern for stateful design?"

Comment: Maybe update the question with what the domain problem is and how you are modelling it? In theory Akka should be able to handle this but there may be better ways to model the domain